# highcharts pie chart color for dynamic data

Tags: jquery, json, highcharts

I have an pie chart which is as follows

```
{
  type : 'pie',
  data : [], //here i'm getting dynamic data
  center : [50, 15 ],
  size : 80,
  showInLegend : false,
  dataLabels :  enabled: true,
}
```

And i want to change color of pie chart

My main question is
Is it possible to set color here by some attribute or i have to get it from dynamic data

**update**

got answer

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
  colors: ['#F64A16', '#0ECDFD',]
});
```

Comment: You should answer your own question and mark it as accepted.

Comment: I can't do upto 8hrs so i put it as update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an answer

we can set highchart custom color by  setOption function
which is as

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
  colors: ['#F64A16', '#0ECDFD',]
});
```

It sets color to my pie chart.

**Another solution for dynamic 3D color**

Actually this customization for theme selection 
Here it is

3 colors sets to color variable

```
var colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors;
        $.each(colors, function(i, color) {
            colors[i] = {
                linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 1, y2: 0 },
                stops: [
                    [0, '#0ECDFD'],
                    [0.3, '#F64A16'],
                    [1, color]
                ]
            };

        });
```

& assign directly in series

```
 {

    type : 'column',
    name : 'bug',
    data : [],
    color : colors,                 
    pointWidth : 28,

}
```